# Create table function SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to create a function which runs a specific query that will extract any `DimPatientID` that is listed within the `DimTestPatient` table. Currently, I use the `WHERE` clause to exclude the test IDs from my query. I would like a function because I will use the `WHERE` clause on almost any query that I will run in the future.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)   
FROM 
    dbo.DimPatient dp
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.FactTreatmentHistory th ON dp.DimPatientID = th.DimPatientID
WHERE
    dp.DimPatientID NOT IN (SELECT DimPatientID
                            FROM dbo.DimTestPatient)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a `VIEW` that doesn't include your test clients?

Answer (score 0):

try using STORED PROCEDURE , it also supports parameters which are handy when you want to return a result set in the form of table.

it can utilise whole query , including WHERE clause as well.
for details follow the below link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16